# Yii CgridView bulk delete

Tags: ajax, yii, cgridview

In many of my Models' CgridViews I have a bulk delete function: a chechboxColumn and a delete button which deletes all the checked users. For that I am using ajax in the admin and a new action in the controller.

All this works fine until I add pagination to th gridview, which is not saving the checked rows in the previous pages.

I tried to use
 'enableHistory'=true,
but it did nothing (and from what I'v read I'm not the only one  :mellow: ) , so I downloaded this extension: selgridview

The extension works - when I move through the pages , the checked rows stay checked BUT , my bulk delete function is seeing only the checked rows of the page I'm in right now.

this is the ajax I'm using:

```
        <?php
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('delete','
    $("#butt").click(function(){
                    var checked=$("#person-grid").yiiGridView("getChecked","person-grid_c11");
                    var count=checked.length;
                    if(count>0 && confirm(" are you sure you want to delete "+count+" people ? "))
                    {
                                    $.ajax({
                                                    data:{checked:checked},
                                                    url:"'.CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('person/remove')).'",
                                                    success:function(data){$("#person-grid").yiiGridView("update",{});},              
                                    });
                    }
                    });
    ');
    ?>
```

Now , maybe thats a silly question but I know little about javascript.
I'm not even sure that the problem is in the ajax . . . .

Help would be much appreciated  :rolleyes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [selgridview extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/selgridview/).

Here is my code for deleting the selected users

```
//delete multiple users at once
$('#delete_selected_items_button').on('click', function () {
    var selected = $("#users-grid").selGridView("getAllSelection");

    //if nothing's selected
    if ( ! selected.length)
    {
        alert('Please select minimum one user to be deleted');
        return false;
    }

    //confirmed?
    if ( ! confirm('Are you sure to delete ' + selected.length + ' users?')) return false;

    var multipledeleteUrl = "<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/users/multipledelete";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: multipledeleteUrl,
        data: {selectedUsers : selected},
        success: (function (e){

            //just to make sure we delete the last selected items
            $("#users-grid").selGridView("clearAllSelection");

            //we refresh the CCGridView after success deletion
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update("users-grid");

        }),
        error: (function (e) {
            alert("Can not delete selected users");
        })
    });
})
```

On `UsersController`, `actionMultipleDelete()` do something like this

```
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        {
            $selectedUsers = Yii::app()->request->getPost('selectedUsers');

            //iterate through all ids
            foreach ($selectedUsers as $id)
            {
                //delete the user here...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know about this plugin and how it saves what checkboxes are
   checked, but you can look into that and then send that information
   to your controller.
2. Alternatively you can save which models should be
   deleted in a session. On a checkbox click() (check if the check box is checked
   or unchecked) event call your controller with ajax to save the
   model's id in your session. then when the user clicks delete you can
   retrieve this data from the session.